# QTreeView grid line color

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I am using QTreeView to display expandable table. But the grid is not showing on QTreeView like on QTableView.

I have tried below code in Ui designer for the property styleSheet of treeview

```
gridline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

But still the grid lines are invisible. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hack:

```
QTreeView::item { border: 0.5px ; border-style: solid ; border-color: lightgray ;}
```

Comment: Hi just one more doubt, I don't need `border-style: solid`, I tried `border-style: thin` but the grid disappears.

Comment: Yes, it is not the recommended solution from Qt team (as far as I understand they recommend to reimplement `paint` for your custom delegate). So, it is just a hack which works.

Comment: If I use this in Qt5 then the background color change when hovering over lines disappears. Similar when selecting items. Selected items become basically invisible because there is no contrast between the foreground and background colors.